# Deserialize Xml Using Same Object With Different Element Name

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an EventType and Events classes to serialize/deserialize. In Xml for Events there is a XmlElement named "type".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events type="array">
   <event>
      <where />
      <project-users-can-edit type="boolean">false</project-users-can-edit>
      <description />
      <attending-user-ids type="integer">164316</attending-user-ids>
      <notify-user-names>Levent A.</notify-user-names>
      <attending-user-names>Levent A.</attending-user-names>
      <status>active</status>
      <owner>
         <first-name>Levent</first-name>
         <id type="integer">164316</id>
         <last-name>Arık</last-name>
      </owner>
      <reminders type="array" />
      <notify-user-ids type="integer">164316</notify-user-ids>
      <start>2015-06-22T00:00</start>
      <repeat />
      <all-day type="boolean">true</all-day>
      <id type="integer">608945</id>
      <end>2015-06-22T23:59</end>
      <show-as-busy type="boolean">false</show-as-busy>
      <last-changed-on type="date">2015-07-08T09:20:37Z</last-changed-on>
      <privacy>
         <type>company</type>
      </privacy>
      <attendees-can-edit type="boolean">false</attendees-can-edit>
      *<type>
         <name>Yıllık İzin</name>
         <id type="integer">104109</id>
         <color>C65518</color>
      </type>*
      <title>Yıllıkİzin</title>
   </event>
</events>
```

But I also have an Xml with the list of EventTypes and with the different xmlelement name "eventtypes".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventtypes type="array">
   <eventtype>
      <name>Diğer</name>
      <id type="integer">104285</id>
      <color>E7C342</color>
   </eventtype>
   <eventtype>
      <name>Hastalık</name>
      <id type="integer">104284</id>
      <color>399A5A</color>
   </eventtype>
   <eventtype>
      <name>Mazeret İzni</name>
      <id type="integer">104110</id>
      <color>633C9C</color>
   </eventtype>
   <eventtype>
      <name>ResmiTatil</name>
      <id type="integer">104286</id>
      <color type="integer">737173</color>
   </eventtype>
   <eventtype>
      <name>Yıllık İzin</name>
      <id type="integer">104109</id>
      <color>C65518</color>
   </eventtype>
</eventtypes>
```

I am using below class for this. But when I want to deserialize eventtypes Xml I have an exception because of title of XmlRoot attribute.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("type")]
public class EventType
{
    public EventType()
    {

    }
    [XmlElement("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I know i can write 2 different classes with same properties. But i wonder if there is another way to do it.

Comment: I would create a 2nd class that inherit the 1st class.  The only difference is the 2nd class would have a different XmlRoot name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`XmlRootAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute only controls the element name used for a type when that type (or an enumerable of that type) is the root element of the document.  Otherwise, the property name or [`XmlElementAttribute.ElementName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value of the property referring to the type controls the XML element name.  Thus, there is no conflict having different element names for your `EventType` class when contained in different outer classes, like so:

```
[XmlRoot("eventtypes")]
public class EventTypeList
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("eventtype")]
    public List<EventType> EventTypes { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("events")]
public class EventList
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("event")]
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("event")]
public class Event // Prototype implementation only, many properties omitted.
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // Remainder omitted for brevity.

    [XmlElement("type")]
    public EventType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DjqlnS).

Incidentally, you can remove the [`Serializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute from you class since it's only useful for binary serialization:

```
[XmlRoot("type")]
public class EventType
{
    public EventType() { }
    [XmlElement("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```